# I can't delete emails in Outlook when searching

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I need to delete many emails containing certain words in the subject. These emails have come to me all the time, so I can't just do a shift click to delete a range. Rather, I want to filter out everything that I don't want to delete so that I can then just delete what I want. To do this I've searched "This is part of the subject" in the "Search Current Mailbox" box.

Problem is that if I delete any emails inside that filtered view the deletion doesn't take. The emails are still in my inbox. If I remove the filtering I can manually delete any email I want, but as I said there are so many so that won't work.

Comment: Web Mail or Desktop Outlook. I enter a search term, press enter, get a list and deleting from this list works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure? Yes, the search result still shows them, but in reality they are gone, and if you refresh (F5), they are gone from the search result too.

Comment: Yes. Delete from the search window results moves the item to Deleted Folder.  Then I closed the Search Window, the email was still Deleted (in Deleted Items).

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of your Outlook? (File > Office Account > About Outlook). Please make sure you have upgraded your Outlook to the latest version.

Based on my test, delete the items in the search result(as shown in the below figure), then the deleted email will not appear in the original folder and will be moved to the deleted folder. It is suggested that you could try to create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add the account for testing to check if there are some differences.

[image]

If the issue still exists, considering that it would also be affected when the Outlook program itself is damaged, it is recommended that you try to [fix the Office application](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is poor UI design. The emails are being deleted. They simply continue to show in the list of the Search results. I believe they should either be removed from the Search results list if you don't have include deleted items on OR the folder location should update to the Deleted folder.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).